# List directory files in a order and replace using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a remote directory under it I have a folder structure as below

```
Logs 
Data
Install
Rollback
```

I know how to display from the directory in question but I need the output in following sequence sorted by lastwritetime.

```
\\shareddrive\xyz\Install\file1
\\shareddrive\xyz\Install\file2
\\shareddrive\xyz/Install\file3
\\shareddrive\xyz\Rollback\file1
\\shareddrive\xyz\Data\file1
\\shareddrive\xyz\Logs\file1
```

Now replace directory location in text file as below

```
..\xyz\Install\file1
..\xyz\Install\file2
..\xyz/Install\file3
..\xyz\Rollback\file1
..\xyz\Data\file1
..\xyz\Logs\file1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you are asking for the files to be output in that exact order. To take a slightly different take on gathering the data I present the following:

```
$uncPath = "\\servername\xyz"
[void]($uncPath -match '^(?<Server>\\\\\w+)')
$shareServerRegex = [regex]::Escape($Matches.Server)
$shareServerReplacement = ".."
$folderOrder = "\Install\","\Rollback\","\Data\","\Logs\"
$data = Get-ChildItem $uncPath -Recurse

$folderOrder | ForEach-Object{
    $currentFolder = [regex]::escape($_)
    $data | Where-Object{$_.FullName -match $currentFolder} | 
           Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
           ForEach-Object{$_.FullName -replace $shareServerRegex,$shareServerReplacement}
} | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath c:\pathtofile.txt
```

`$uncPath` contains the path to the folder we are going to parse from. To make the script a little more dynamic we gather the \serverpath into $Matches.Server and the use the static method of `Escape` from regex to build the regex match string we will use soon to massage the path as you requested. Gather all the files from the `$uncPath` into the variable `$data`. Using the `$folderOrder` array we go though each item and select the files that have that as part of the folder path. You will see that the array has the folders with a slash before and after. That will ensure no files themselves, containing any of those words, end up filtered in the wrong order. Again, since we use slashes that are control characters in regex we use the `Escape` method to match the files from `$data` we need what I presume is the correct order. Proof is in the pudding.

```
..\xyz\Install\file1                                                             
..\xyz\Install\file2
..\xyz\Install\file3                                                             
..\xyz\Rollback\file1                                                            
..\xyz\Data\file1                                                                
..\xyz\Logs\file1
```

In short all I was trying to help you address is the output. You can ignore all my other code and just focus on what I think you needed help with. This will work as long as you populate `$data` and set or replace the parameters of `-replace`

```
$folderOrder = "\Install\","\Rollback\","\Data\","\Logs\"
...
$folderOrder | ForEach-Object{
    $currentFolder = [regex]::escape($_)
    $data | Where-Object{$_.FullName -match $currentFolder} | 
           Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
           ForEach-Object{$_.FullName -replace $shareServerRegex,$shareServerReplacement}
} | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath c:\pathtofile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, how to write result to a text file and the files inside should be order by last changed date ex:if have 3 files in folder install order should be based on changed date. I am new to powershell trying to learn things

Comment: Thats not too hard since we already have the data. I assumed you would know how to export it but i can add it in for you

Comment: i removed -file to make it work . thanks i need order files inside sub folder based on modified date and write it to a text file i really appreciate your help

Comment: @Sursh See if this fits your needs. If not please explain with the most information possible as to what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you again I need to remove -file to make it work. For some reason the file that created is 0 kb and results are displayed in powershell window

Comment: For my own debugging i had `$data` on its own line. I removed it. I dont have real data to play with so for starters I would remove the `| Out-File ...` and you can debug it from there. I can try to reproduce this with real data but that might take a little time.

Comment: @Sursh you are changing all the paths to meet your needs correct?

Comment: Yes Sir i did. but some reason its doesnt export

Comment: @Sursh I have my test data now and am looking at it.

Comment: @Sursh ok... behold the marverlous, tested, pretty sure it will work for you __CODE__!